# Constrained optimization over vectors

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces

**Edit:** Even strategies for attack (as opposed to complete answers) are appreciated-- this is a hard question.

I have a function $f(v,p)$ where v is a vector of length $n$, and I'm trying to derive lower and upper bounds $L$ and $U$ on $f$ for each value of $p \geq 1$, where the vector $v$ is subject to some simple constraints (the first element of $v$ is always 1 and the remaining elements are in $[0,1]$):

Find $L(p,n)$, $U(p,n)$ s.t.
$f(v,p) \in [L(p,n), U(p,n)]$ when $p\geq 1$ and 
$v_1 = 1$ and $\forall i \in \{2, 3, \ldots n\}~ v_i \in [0,1]$.

$f$ is a function of different norms of $v$ (I've used the shorthand $v_{(a)}^{(b)} = \| v \|_{a p}^{b p}$ to condense the expression):

$f(v,p) = {\left( \frac{ v_{(1)}^{(1)} v_{(4)}^{(4)} - v_{(2)}^{(2)} v_{(3)}^{(3)} + \sqrt{ v_{(1)}^{(2)} v_{(4)}^{(8)} - 6 v_{(1)}^{(1)} v_{(2)}^{(2)} v_{(3)}^{(3)} v_{(4)}^{(4)} + 4 v_{(1)}^{(1)} v_{(3)}^{(9)} + 4 v_{(2)}^{(6)} v_{(4)}^{(4)} - 3 v_{(2)}^{(4)} v_{(3)}^{(6)} } }{ 2 (v_{(1)}^{(1)} v_{(3)}^{(3)} - v_{(2)}^{(4)}) } \right)}^\frac{1}{p}$

and where the denominator is known to be nonzero, which I believe implies that at least one other element $j \neq 1$ where $v_j \in (0,1)$.

**Do you know of a good way to find expressions $L(p,n)$ and $U(p,n)$ to satisfy this?** I tried starting with KKT and working backwards and haven't yet gotten an answer, and questioned whether that was really the right plan of attack.

**Where this messy expression came from:** I'm doing a statistical derivation, where I would ideally have $f(v,p)$ is an imperfect estimate of a value that in reality equals $1$. The lower and upper bound for each $p$ (i.e., $L(p,n)$ and $U(p,n)$) show the worst-case for how close this estimate is to $1$ for any given $p$.

I've simulated the above expression numerically (randomly sampling $10,000$ vectors $v$ by drawing uniform values in $[0,1]$ for $v_2, v_3 \ldots$ for short vectors $n \in \{3,4,5\}$), and have observed the following:

(Note that the red curve should always be at least as extreme and green, since $\mathbb{R}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \subset \mathbb{R}^5$; however, in the simulations this is not always the case simply because there wasn't sufficient saturation of samples.

**Lower bound of $f$:**
[image: Lower bound]

**Upper bound of $f$:**
[image: Upper bound]

**Absolute $L_1$ error bound $| f-1 |$:**
[image: Absolute error bound]